# D3.js appending elements on enter() but not always removing on exit()

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm using d3 to create a bunch of list items for a data set of unresponsive computers in student labs. The data looks like this

```
{
    "LabName": "All",
    "Computers": [
        {
            "Hostname": "computer76",
            "Lab": "Lab-101"
        },
        {
            "Hostname": "computer78",
            "Lab": "Lab-101"
        },
        {
            "Hostname": "computer117",
            "Lab": "Lab-211"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this data I want to populate a list which is organised by lab with a heading

I went about it by making the containers using another data set that lists all the labs so the containers are sitting there ready.

The containers look like this

```
<div class="notify" id="Lab-101">
    <h4>Lab-101</h4>
</div>
```

In my first attempt I tried to go through the data (computers) and for each computer filter the data to only computers in that lab, then bind that data to `li`s in the specific div that is to show those items. Then since that lab is done, I'll skip the next computer if it's the same lab.

I get the enter items but *not always* the exit.

```
studentsDown = thisLabsDownData["Computers"];
// studentsDown is sorted on "Lab"
var prevLab = null;
studentsDown.forEach(function (val, ind, obj) {
    var labName = val.Lab;

    if (prevLab != labName) {
        var thisLabsComputers = studentsDown.filter(function (d) { return d.Lab == labName });
        thisLabsComputers.sort(GetSortOrder("Hostname"));
        var selector = "#notify-student-" + labName;

        var stuItems = d3.select(selector).selectAll("li")
            .data(thisLabsComputers, function (d) { return d.Hostname; });

        stuItems.enter().append("li")
            .html(function (d) { return d.Hostname; });

        stuItems.exit().remove();
    }
    prevLab = labName;
});
```

**Attempt 2**

I have had this working on a previous set of data which had a slightly different format but which didn't need to append to individual containers, so I convert the data to the following format first

```
[
  {
    "LabName": "Lab-211",
    "Computers": [
      "computer117"
    ]
  },
  {
    "LabName": "Lab-101",
    "Computers": [
      "computer76",
      "computer78"
    ]
   }
  ]
```

And then

```
studentLabs.forEach(function (val, ind, obj) {
    val.Computers.sort();
    labName = val.LabName;
    var selector = "#notify-student-" + labName;

    var stuItems = d3.select(selector).selectAll("li")
        .data(val.Computers, function (d, i) { return d; });

    stuItems.enter().append("li")
        .html(function (d, i) { return d; });

    stuItems.exit().remove();
});
```

I thought perhaps the heading was messing with the indexing of the item so I moved that out into a parent element

```
<div id="lab-student-RH-106">
    <h4>RH-106</h4>
    <div class="notify" id="notify-student-RH-106">

    </div>
</div>
```

But new items still appear but dont exit

Some additional notes about the behaviour

if a lab already has list items in it the enter and exit will work. If there are no items in a lab and 3 are entered at the same time, the exit wont work for any, they stay. What am I overlooking or not understanding?

In the meantime I'll try to get rid of the containers and get it back to basics to see if I can get it working and build it up again.

I also have jQuery 3.1.1 and wonder if that's interfering, attempts to get the data from the API without jQuery have been unsuccessful so I can't remove it and test. I think it's unlikely but worth mentioning.

**Progress**

I've got it working almost completely now. The key aspects so far is using the data to add the lab containers, then using `.each()` on those so the data is maintained, and using `this` so the element is maintained and drilling in to add the computer `li`s.

```
var labItems = d3.select("#studentsDownDetail").selectAll("div")
    .data(studentLabs, function (d, i) { return d.LabName; });

labItems.enter().append("div")
    .html(function (d, i) { return "<h4>" + d.LabName + "</h4>" })
    .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "notify-student-" + d.LabName });

labItems.each(function (d, i) {
    var thisOne = d3.select(this).selectAll("li")
        .data(d.Computers, function (d, i) { return d });

    thisOne.enter().append("li")
        .html(function (d, i) { return d });

    thisOne.exit().each(function (d, i) { /* some extra stuff here */ }).remove();
});

labItems.exit().each(function (d, i) { /* something here */ }).remove();
```

The problem is that I want to create a notification for each time a computer comes up or leaves the data. This allows me to do that except if the lab exits the data (because all computers are now available) as this means there is no lab item to drill into to throw a `.exit` for the computer item.

Probably workable - so close!

As it is the lab is only added on the first update and the computers within are only added on the next update. Adding the `.each` function on the `.enter` as well as the 'update' should fix that.

**Final Puzzle Pieces**

```
    labItems.exit().each(function (d, i) { /*
use d.Computers to access that last computer on exit
*/  }).remove();
```

Comment: The problem here is easy to spot: the `forEach` loop. You're creating an update/enter/exit selection for each data point, and that simply doesn't work. If you want to append the computers in different divs, one for each lab, the best idea is nesting the data array, and creating two nested selections, one for the divs and another one for the lists. For a proper answer, please share two data sets (the initial one and the final one) and the method to update them (a button, a timeout etc...), so we can write a proper answer.

Comment: Easy for some I guess. Though it does work to an extent - all enters work and some exits work. To my thinking I am creating update/enter/exit selections for different data sets (extracting them from a larger set) and applying them to different elements. Why would that not work?

Comment: No, you're not creating an update/ente/exit selection for each data set, you're creating them for each element in the "Computers" array. That's what the `forEach` is doing here. As a rule of thumb, never use any loop for creating selections in a D3 code.

Comment: Apologies to anyone viewing - I'll write this up into an answer and remove the updates from the question - but feel free to suggest improvements